# Cannot get data from array when using fetch API javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using swapi api to get starwars planet data

this is the code:

```
var data = [];
let url = 'https://swapi.boom.dev/api/planets/';
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
let fetched = fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
.then(json => json.results)
.then(results => data.push(results[i].name))
}
```

when i run `console.log(data)`
it returns this array: [image: array]

now when i try to use its data and run `console.log(data[0])`
it returns `undefined`

what shoud i do?

Comment: Where are you putting the `console.log`? You're pushing to `data`. Why?

Comment: i put console log in the same file. I forgot to add the data=[] in the question

Comment: Explanation about the behavior you see: You get an **empty array** logged (`Array []`) because you access it while it wasn't filled yet (the promise will resolve only later on). But when you click the arrow in the console, due to **lazy expansion**, you'll see the contents at the point in time when you clicked the arrow, at which point the contents already _will_ have been filled in.

Comment: How can i store the data in an array and then use it?